# How to show a "no results" message when no rows are found?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When no rows are found, how do I show a "no results found" message?

```
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $matched = false;
 while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 {
    $matched = true;
    echo $row['name'];
 }
 if(!$matched)
     echo "no any";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one..

```
$kittens = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

if(!$kittens )
{
    //Nada
}
else
{
    foreach($kittens as $kitten)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative solution, you could add a if condition.

```
if ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo $row['name'];
   while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['name'];
   } 
} else {
   echo "no results found";
}
```